# How to Remove Rows from DataFrame Based on Values in Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I know it's an easy question, but I just can't find a way to solve it.

I have a `DataFrame` that I want to remove rows based on values in another `series`.

```
X
   1   2   5   6   7   10  12  13
0   5   4   4   4   0   4   0   3
1   3   0   3   0   0   0   0   3
2   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   3   0   0   0   5   4   5   5
4   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1 

Vtk
1    4
2    3
4    3
Name: rank, dtype: int64
```

I want to remove rows from *X* that correspond the index of value `a = 3` in *Vtk*. In this case, I'm expecting rows from *X* with index `2` and `4` to be removed, based on value `a = 3`. Like this :

```
X
   1   2   5   6   7   10  12  13
0   5   4   4   4   0   4   0   3
1   3   0   3   0   0   0   0   3
3   3   0   0   0   5   4   5   5
```

So far I've tried :

```
b = Vtk.isin([~a])
newX = X.loc[b]
```

but there's as IndexingError :

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

First filter index values by `Series` and then remove rows by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
b = Vtk.index[Vtk == 3]
print (b)
Int64Index([2, 4], dtype='int64')

newX = X.drop(b)
print (newX)
   1  2  5  6  7  10  12  13
0  5  4  4  4  0   4   0   3
1  3  0  3  0  0   0   0   3
3  3  0  0  0  5   4   5   5
```

Another solution with filtering with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with `~` for inverse mask:

```
newX = X[~X.index.isin(b)]
print (newX)
   1  2  5  6  7  10  12  13
0  5  4  4  4  0   4   0   3
1  3  0  3  0  0   0   0   3
3  3  0  0  0  5   4   5   5
```

And solution with selecting by `loc` is get values of indices by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
newX = X.loc[X.index.difference(b)]
print (newX)
   1  2  5  6  7  10  12  13
0  5  4  4  4  0   4   0   3
1  3  0  3  0  0   0   0   3
3  3  0  0  0  5   4   5   5
```

Comment: Got it, your reply helps! Thanks!